# How do you add a string in a print f statement

Tags: java, printf

```
        System.out.printf("\t\t\t\t~~~~ %.2f%%\n", percent, "success! ~~~~" + "\n");
```

I want the output to be `~~~~100.0% success! ~~~~`, but it's giving me only `~~~~100.0%`. How do I fix this?

I tried using `+`, but it gave me a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it with `%s` in the format string:

```java
System.out.printf("\t\t\t\t~~~~ %.2f%% %s", percent, "success! ~~~~" + "\n");
```

Alternatively, you can just add the text inside the format string:

```java
System.out.printf("\t\t\t\t~~~~ %.2f%% success! ~~~~\n", percent);
```